# Yii2- How to restrict a user from viewing others data in index page

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, access-control, yii2-user, yii2-user-roles

I am working on `yii2` in my project, I have users and their roles. Each role is given access to a Module and a Sub Menu. There is a sub-menu named `SIM List` in which all the `SIM` records can be viewed. There is a field named `issued_to` which tells us that which SIM has been issued to which user.

Unless a SIM is issued to any user, the `issued_to` field will remain empty. Once issued the name of the user will appear on the `SIM List`.

Now I want to manage it in such a way that only a specific user can see the list. For example `5 Sims` have been issued to a user named `U`. Now the user `U` should only see that SIM records which are issued to him, otherwise the list should be empty.

In my `Index` controller I am getting `issued_to` field name which is empty by default.

```
 public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new SimsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

By doing like below I can get `issued_to` user id

```
$model = $dataProvider->getModels()[0];
$user_id =  $model['issued_to'];
var_dump($user_id);
exit();
```

Now in this controller, I want to add a check of `user_id` which gives me only the records which are of that specific user.

**Index View**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'id',
        'imsi',
        'sim_number',
        'operator_name',
        'data_details',
        'sms_details',
        'monthly_bill',
        //'created_by',
        [
            'label' => 'Created By',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                if (is_object($data))
                    return $data->created->name;
                return ' - ';
            },
            //'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'created_by', \app\models\User::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Created By", 'class' => 'form-control']),
        ],
        'created_at',
        // 'updated_at',
        'status',
        // 'updated_by',
        //'sim_stauts',
        [
            'label'=>'SIM Status',
            'value'=>function($a){
                return $a->getStatusvalue();
            }
        ],
        //'issued_to',
        [
            'label' => 'Issued To',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                if(is_object($d->user))
                    //return $d->user->name;
                    return $d->issued_to == '' ? '' : $d->user->username;
                return ' - ';
                // return $d->user->name;

            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'issued_to', \app\models\User::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Users", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
       //'returned_by',
        [
            'label' => 'Returned By',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                if(is_object($d->user2))
                    //return $d->user->name;
                    return $d->returned_by == '' ? '' : $d->user->username;
                return ' - ';
                // return $d->user->name;

            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'returned_by', \app\models\User::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Users", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
        'historic',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

**Update 1**

My `search model` is below

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Sims::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'created_by' => $this->created_by,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'updated_by' => $this->updated_by,
        'sim_stauts' => $this->sim_stauts,
        'issued_to' => $this->issued_to,
        'returned_by' => $this->returned_by,
        'historic' => $this->historic,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'imsi', $this->imsi])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sim_number', $this->sim_number])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'operator_name', $this->operator_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'data_details', $this->data_details])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sms_details', $this->sms_details])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'monthly_bill', $this->monthly_bill])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'status', $this->status]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

How can I achieve it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: add your `SimsSearch` model

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have added the search model

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam still waiting :(

Comment: yaar aik to tu sath hi muu bana leta hai **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯** **`:D`**, was really busy in a project could get time to attend here. added an answer for you hope it helps you out.

Comment: hahaha... ok bro ab nahi bnata mun ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your description, you have the `user_id` saved inside the `issued_to` field and you need to only fetch the results that have the current logged in `user_id` saved in the field `issued_to`.

I assume that your search in the grid view is visible to only logged-in users.

You should set the `issued_to` param manually by first getting the `queryParams` array from the `request` object `Yii::$app->request->queryParams;` which has the array in the same format as the `POST` has i.e **`['ModelName']['field_name']`** so you need to infact set the `issued_to` as

```
$arrayParams['SimSearch']['issued_to']=Yii:$app->user->id;
```

Your `actionIndex` should look like below

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new SimsSearch();
    $queryParams=Yii::$app->request->queryParams;

    //check if user or one of the managers
    $isAdmin=in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role,[1,6]);

    //set params if normal user
    if(!$isAdmin){
       $queryParams['SimsSearch']['issued_to']=Yii::$app->user->id;
    }

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: You are a genius bro :)

Comment: :) not really but glad i could help you out.

Comment: No bro you are.. :)

Comment: Bro there is a small issue. Actually it's working only with `issued record`. As the `SIM Manager` and `Admin` should see all records wether issued or not. But for now the SIM List is empty

Comment: so you are using the same controller/action for admins too ? @MrFaisal

Comment: Yes same controller is used for all

Comment: ok, and how are you managing roles, i mean apart from `Sim Manager` and `Admin` role how many roles are there ? @MrFaisal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166009/discussion-between-muhammad-omer-aslam-and-mr-faisal).